# How to pull specific feature from table corresponding to its ID in a text

Tags: python, nlp, pypdf

I have some pdf files with many pages. I read the file into a dictionary, with file name as a key and its text as value.

After each of some given words (search key: ID1 and type in this example) there is a table with **lable**.

I need to extract the information of label that can be separated by "," in list format and insert them into a column of data frame. how should I develop my code ?

**Final out put should looks like :**

```
    ID       label
0   ID1     [yes, no]
1   type    [f1, f2]
```

**Sample of  raw table**

ID1: drug ever used

aaaa bbb

| label | header |
| --- | --- |
| yes | a1 |
| no | b1 |

type: pill ever used

cccc

| label | header |
| --- | --- |
| f1 | a1 |
| f3 | b1 |

```
   

#text : is the content of pdf that I converted to a text.


def read_pdfs(dictionary):
    dfs_names_text_dic = {}
    for pdf_file, name in dictionary.items():
        pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        output = []
        for i in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            output.append(pageObj.extractText())
        dfs_names_text_dic[name] = output
        pdfFileObj.close()
    return dfs_names_text_dic

out put example:
dic = {pdf_name1 : text, pdf_name2:text }
```

Comment: please add the current output and the expected output as well

Comment: Expected output is inside the question and it is bold.

Comment: If you want to consider PyMuPDF, your will find a an example [here](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/table-analysis/gridlines-to-pandas.py) which can extract data from tables with full gridlines.

Comment: Try https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot